# Next.js 13 errors.tsx

Tags: next.js13

I'm just playing around with nextjs 13, and I came across the error.{js,jsx,ts,tsx} file naming convention. But when the following code ran, I never saw the error component.

page.tsx

```
'use client';

export default function RootPage(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    throw new Error('Test');
                }}
            >
                Error
            </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

error.tsx

```
'use client';

type Props = {
    error: Error & { digest?: string };
    reset: VoidFunction;
};

export default function HomePageError({ error, reset }: Props): JSX.Element {
    return <>{error.message && error.message}</>;
}
```

Did I misunderstand the purpose of error.tsx file or is there something that I needed to do first in order for next to render the error component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js 13's `error.tsx` file convention is based on [React's Error Boundary](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

Here I quote from React Docs:

> Error boundaries do not catch errors for:
>
> - Event handlers (learn more)
> - Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
> - Server side rendering
> - Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

And in your case, you are throwing an error inside an event handler (`onClick`) which won't be caught by the error boundary.

---

To test `error.tsx` in your Next.js 13 app, you can try this instead:

```
// page.tsx
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';

export default function RootPage(): JSX.Element {
    const [testError, setTestError] = useState(false);

    if (testError) throw new Error('test error.tsx');

    return (
        <>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setTestError(true);
                }}
            >
                Error
            </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize this was not meant to be caught by the Error Boundary